# Proving that a function is null.

Tags: real-analysis

Let $a \in  \mathbb{R}_{+*}$
and $f:\mathbb{R}_{+*}\rightarrow \mathbb{R}  $ a postive function and differentiable

and $f(0)=0$  and $f'(x) \leq af(x).$

Prove that $f(x)=0$ for all $x \in  \mathbb{R}_{+}$

you can use the function $g(x)=e^{-ax}f(x)$

I have $g'(x)=e^{-ax}(f'(x)-af(x))\leq 0$ so the function $g$ is decreasing
so $g(x)\leq g(0)=0$

how I can prove that $f(x)=0$

Comment: $0\le g(x)\le g(0)=0$, so …?

Comment: thanks i didn't notice that g(x) is positive

Comment: Please use capital letters when using the pronoun "I".